# Cannot get Scrapy to work on Mac Os Catalina

Tags: web, scrapy, screen-scraping

After trying to continuously trying to install and run scrapy, i have hit a wall and cannot figure out what else to do.

upon initialising venv within folder with python 3.6.12,

```
scrapy startproject scraperproj
```

i am presented with the following error

```
`ImportError: dlopen(/Users/adris/Desktop/webscraper/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.7.dylib
```

Referenced from: /Users/adris/Desktop/webscraper/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-36m-darwin.so
Reason: Incompatible library version: _cffi_backend.cpython-36m-darwin.so requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libffi.7.dylib provides version 1.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

after 8 hours of continuous efforts, i tried myself at pip installing via using pip3 seemed to do the job! all working now